# Wakanda mail does not send

Tags: email, server, wakanda

On serverside (wakanda 10) I send an email with:

```
var mail = require('waf-mail/mail');
var message = new mail.Mail();
message.from = 'emailadres of the sender';
message.to = [theEmailadres];
message.subject = 'Here the subject of the email';
message.setBodyAsHTML('Here the HTML content of the email');
message.send('smtp.gmail.com', 465, true, 'username', 'password');
```

Then it look like the procedure is frozen. When I close the debugger I get in the logfile this error:

> 2016-05-11 15:17:55 [com.wakanda-software.xbox] ERROR - [1]  / Broken pipe (kOTSerialOverrunErr / EPIPE)., task #21523, task name is HTTP connection handler

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Use **mail.send** unstead of **message.send** and add **domain: 'gmail.com'** to the object passed to send()  :

```
var mail = require('waf-mail/mail'); 
var message = new mail.Mail();
message.subject = "Here the subject of the email";
message.from = "emailadres of the sender";
message.to = 'theEmailadres';
message.setBodyAsHTML("Here the HTML content of the email");
mail.send({
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com', 
    port: 465,
    isSSL: true,
    username: 'username', 
    password: 'password', 
    domain: 'gmail.com'
}, message);
```

it works perfectly for me, notice that Google may block the connection attempts, if so enable "access for less secure apps" in the settings of the sender gmail account. [Allow less secure apps to access accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)